# How to use Selenium IDE to verify a HTML element not present

Tags: html, selenium-ide

I am using Selenium IDE on FF to verify that certain HTML source code should NOT appear in the page.

[image]

The syntax I'm using is:

**`Command: verifyNotHtmlSource`**

**`Target: css=iframe#MainFrame`**

**`Value: Cl<sup>-</sup>`**

I executed this command and I expect it to fail (since there is "`Cl<sup>-<sup>`" in the HTML source).
But it passed !!!
[image]

Can we figure out why? How do I verify that "`Cl<sup>-</sup>`" is not in the HTML source ?

Comment: are you sure there's no whitespace between the Cl and the <sup>-</sup> ?

Comment: `<h2>Cl<sup>-</sup></h2>` : I can confirm no whitespaces

Comment: the only link I can find to it suggests that it matches a pattern against the full HTML source, rather than finding your string inside it. Can you try a regex instead of just the string you're trying to find?

Answer (score 0):

how about `assertElementNotPresent | //sup |` or `verifyElementNotPresent | //sup |` ?

Comment: There are many other <sup> elements in the page. I cannot use `assertElementNotPresent | //sup`

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using assertNotVisible with a straightforward css selector to the element; if it doesn't exist, the result will be true.

For example:

```
assertNotVisible
css=h2 sup
```